# Java eclipse tic tac toe game

Tags: java

How do I fix my tic tac toe game?
The code below is as far as I got. It runs but not properly.please help.I'm using eclipse neon

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeGame  {

 // Declare variables

    public char[][] board; //the game board
    public boolean xTurn; //if true X's turn, if false O's turn
    public Scanner keyboard; //reads user input 

    public TicTacToeGame()  {



    xTurn = true;
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create the board
        board = new char[3][3];

        //initialize the board 
        for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)  {

            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                board[r][c] = ' ';
        }
    }

        public void displayRow(int row)  {

            System.out.println(" " + board[row][0] + " | " + board[row][1] + " | " + board[row][2]);
        }


         //the rest of the game board

        public void displayBoard()  {

            displayRow(0);
            System.out.println("-----------");
            displayRow(1);
            System.out.println("-----------");
            displayRow(2);

            System.out.println("Which row, column would you like to move to? Enter two numbers between 0-2 separated by a space to indicate position.");
        }


        public boolean getMove()  {

            boolean invalid = true;
            int row = 0, column = 0;

            //user input
            while(invalid)  {

                row = keyboard.nextInt();
                column = keyboard.nextInt();

                //check for valid spot
                if(row >= 0 && row <= 2 && column >= 0 && column <= 2)  {

                    //check that the position is not taken
                    if(board[row][column] != ' ')
                        System.out.println("That position is already taken");
                    else
                        invalid = false;
                }
            }

            //fill in the game board with the player mark
            if(xTurn)
                board[row][column] = 'X';
            else
                board[row][column] = 'O';

            return winner(row,column);
        }


        //check for win


        public boolean winner(int lastR, int lastC)  {

            boolean winner = false; // no winner
            char symbol = board[lastR][lastC]; //last made mark

            //check left-right
            int numFound = 0;
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)  {
                if(board[lastR][c] == symbol)
                    numFound++;
            }

            if(numFound == 3)
                winner = true;

            //check up-down
            numFound = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)  {
                if(board[r][lastC] == symbol)
                    numFound++;
            }

            if(numFound == 3)
                winner = true;

            //check both diagonals
            numFound = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
                if(board[i][i] == symbol)
                    numFound++;
            }

            if(numFound == 3)
                winner = true;

            numFound = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
                if(board[i][2-i] == symbol)
                    numFound++;
            }

            if(numFound == 3)
                winner = true;

            return winner;
        }


        public boolean boardFull()  {

            //how many spots that are taken by each player
            int numSpotsFilled = 0;

            for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)  {

                for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)  {
                    if(board[r][c] == 'X' || board[r][c] == 'O')
                        numSpotsFilled++;
                }
            }

            return numSpotsFilled == 9;

        }

         //start  game.


        public void play()  {

            while(true)  {

                displayBoard();

                if(xTurn)
                    System.out.println("X's Turn!");
                else
                    System.out.println("O's Turn!");

                int choice = keyboard.nextInt();

                if(choice == 1)  {

                    if(getMove())  {
                        // winner!
                        displayBoard(); //display winner board

                        if(xTurn)
                            System.out.println("X Wins!");
                        else
                            System.out.println("O Wins!");

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(boardFull())  {
                        //tie
                        displayBoard(); //display tie board 

                        System.out.println("Tie!");

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else  {
                        //no winner 
                        xTurn = !xTurn;  //switch players
                    }
                }
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
                    TicTacToeGame game = new TicTacToeGame();

                    game.play();
                }

        }
```

Comment: See: [Why is "can someone help me not a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please explain what doesn't work, the expected output and actual output

Comment: Feel free to expand on *"It runs but not properly"*

Comment: when it first runs the board is there but you have to put the col row twice to place a mark for every turn.

Comment: What is `choice` used for?

Comment: I recently deleted that. i was told to add that. when i did it did not run at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `play()` method you're reading a variable called `choice` which is never used (but to start the game), if you remove these lines:

```
int choice = keyboard.nextInt(); //Remove this line

if (choice == 1) { //Remove this line
    //Keep the code here
} //Remove this line
```

Your game will run properly.

Otherwise if you run with an input: `2 0` for example it will never work.

I also recommend you to **always** use the curly braces for your `if-else` / `for` / `while` / etc instructions.

Comment: I took those lines out and it would not run. should I take something else out?

Comment: Probably you took out some other code out before it, copy-paste the code you posted and remove the lines I said...

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but please don't forget to take the [tour] so your questions don't get downvoted (and you get banned from asking questions because of it) and learn [ask]